# Heroku db:migrate error

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem with RoR + Heroku :
Console log:

```
    C:\Users\Admin\RoR\demo_app>heroku run rake db:migrate
    Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.1
    rake aborted!
    Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adap
    ter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)

    Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Gemfile:

```
    source 'http://rubygems.org'
    gem 'rails', '3.1.1'


    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.3'


    group :assets do
      gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
      gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
      gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
    end

    gem 'jquery-rails'

    group :test do
      # Pretty printed test output
      gem 'turn', :require => false
    end

    group :production do
      gem 'pg'
    end
    group :development, :test do
      gem "sqlite3-ruby", :require => "sqlite3"
    end
```

I read need fix database.uml "postgres" -> "postgresql", but i'm not find this cod :(
database.uml :

```
    development:
      adapter: sqlite3
      database: db/development.sqlite3
      pool: 5
      timeout: 5000

    # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
    # re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
    # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
    test:
      adapter: sqlite3
      database: db/test.sqlite3
      pool: 5
      timeout: 5000

    production:
      adapter: sqlite3
      database: db/production.sqlite3
      pool: 5
      timeout: 5000
```

And I install pg, Gemfile.log:
`pg (0.11.0-x86-mingw32)`

I don't know what me doing :(
P.S. sorry, my English is not good, I'm from Russia(
З.Ы. Может кто по русски ответит, буду очень признателен)(

Answer (score 2):

Just change the gem 'sqlite3' to gem 'pg' in the gem file.
Then bundle install and then go in a sequential manner as shown [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3).

First you have to deploy your app onto heroku then omnly you can migrate your data to the app.